# Laravel 5 migration error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-5

I was using migration with a database. Then i removed that database and created new one. Then i created migration files from the terminal via `php artisan make:migration create_users`.

Then i came back and tried to run the migration and it throws the following error with `php artisan migrate`

Error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message 'The stream or file
>   "/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be
>   opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:95

And also a few more.

I googled and found that `composer dump-autoload` wil work, But it didn't and `composer dump-autoload` throws the same error.

`php artisan migrate:reset` throws the same error as `php artisan migrate:reset`.

Thanks

Comment: Problem with laravel log. give read and write permission to storage/logs/

Comment: i set the permissions correctly now it throws error [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'firstapp' i deleted firstapp database before and now in config/database.php file have fts_laravel database and it is correct . Any idea ?

Comment: firstapp database is not exist

Comment: yes firstapp database does not exists and i have now `fts_laravel` which is correct in `config/database.php` file.

Comment: change database name .env file in root folder of laravel

Comment: Oh yeahhhhhh ! 
Thanks buddy !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Permission of log folder of laravel

Give Read & Write permission

```
storage/logs
```

Changing Database:

1: Change DB name in config/database.php

2: `root/.env DB_DATABASE=databasename`

Answer (score 0):

It's not the problem of autoloading. It is a problem of file permissions. Check if webserver can write to the `storage/logs` directory.

Comment: i set the permissions correctly now it throws error `[PDOException]                                      
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'firstapp' `

i deleted  firstapp database before and now in `config/database.php` file have fts_laravel database and it is correct . 
Any idea ?